# How to include native library on maven's java.library.path variable

Tags: maven, native

I am trying to use JNotify for my application , which has the following requirements

> JNotify can be tested by simply running the jar file with the followng commend:
> java -Djava.library.path=. -jar jnotify-VER.jar [dir]
>
> JNotify will then monitor the specified dir (or the current directory if dir is not specified) and print detected events. Note that **java.library.path** should point to the **location of the native libraries** that comes with jnotify (dlls, so dylibs etc).

But trying to get the same thing working with maven is not working out. I am trying to run a simple test but I get the following error

```
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnotify in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1738)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
    at net.contentobjects.jnotify.linux.JNotify_linux.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at net.contentobjects.jnotify.linux.JNotifyAdapterLinux.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

which means the native files are not found on the library path.

My pom.xml looks like this -

I have added the jar and .so to our internal repository

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>net.contentobjects</groupId>
            <artifactId>jnotify</artifactId>
            <version>0.93</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
           <groupId>net.contentobjects</groupId>
           <artifactId>jnotify</artifactId>
           <version>0.93</version>
           <type>so</type>
</dependency>


<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
            <argLine>-Djava.library.path=target/lib/</argLine>
     </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
     <executions>
       <execution>
              <id>copy</id>
              <phase>compile</phase>
              <goals>
                     <goal>copy</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                    <artifactItems>
                      <artifactItem>
                             <groupId>net.contentobjects</groupId>
                             <artifactId>jnotify</artifactId>
                             <version>0.93</version>
                             <type>so</type>
                             <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                      <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                     </artifactItem>
                     </artifactItems>
               </configuration>
             </execution>
          </executions>
 </plugin>
```

This doesn't work though, any ideas whats missing?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the dependency .so file get copied into the target directory in the compile phase?  Is it named correctly?  Likely it will be named something like jnotify-0.93.so.

If you need it named just jnotify.so, you might want to tryt to turn on the [stripVersion](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html#stripVersion) option of the maven-dependency-plugin's copy goal.

Comment: Thanks. I needed to rename the file using `destFileName>libjnotify.so</destFileName>`. I couldnt use stripversion since I am using Maven 2.2