# Maven and native library files

Tags: java, maven, project-management, native

I have a library that gets used in a mavenized java projects. The library is composed of two parts: a jar that exposes the API, and 3 dlls (native lib). There is a piece of code in the jar that loads the dlls, so the directory where the dlls are located has to be in the PATH environment variable.

Adding the jar to my project was easy. The way I have the dll set up is each developer downloads the dlls into a directory then adds the path-to-dlls to the PATH environment variable.

Ideally I'd like there to be as little set-up possible when a new developer downloads the project. Is there a better way to set the dlls up (without the overhead of downloading them separate from the project, and adding the directory to PATH)?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073039/how-to-include-native-library-on-mavens-java-library-path-variable?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, that solves one of my problems (running tests in a test server). But each developer still has to point PATH to the directory containing the dlls to be able to run code locally (say from IntelliJ IDEA). Is there no work around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can change the loading code of the library: Include the DLLs in your jar/classpath.  Then [copy](https://commons.apache.org/io/) the DLL files to the local file system.  Load from there.  The following assumes library is on the classpath.

```
public void loadLibrary(String library) throws IOException {
    InputStream source = getClass().getResourceAsStream(library);
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("javatmp", ".dll");
    FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
    try {
        IOUtils.copy(source, dest)
    }
    finally {
        dest.close();
        source.close();
    }
    System.load(tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
    tempFile.delete();
}
```

If you can't change how the library loads DLLs, then you could modify the PATH (using [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna)) and copy the DLLs to that location.  The following assumes library is on the root of the classpath.

```
public void exposeLibrary(String library, File tempDir) throws IOException {
    InputStream source = getClass().getResourceAsStream(library);
    File tempFile = new File(tempDir, library);
    FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
    try {
        IOUtil.copy(source, dest)
    }
    finally {
        dest.close();
        source.close();
    }    
    WinLibc.INSTANCE._putenv("PATH=" + 
        System.getenv().get("PATH") + File.pathSeparator + tempDir.getAbsolutePath());

    // After this point System.loadLibrary(library) will load the DLL.
}


public interface WinLibC extends Library {
  static WinLibC INSTANCE = Native.loadLibrary("msvcrt", WinLibC.class);

  public int _putenv(String name);
}
```

Note: I didn't test any of this. The 2nd solution won't work for Linux (but could with a few [changes](http://quirkygba.blogspot.com/2009/11/setting-environment-variables-in-java.html).)